# new directory is not created

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am unable to create a directory using the following program :

```
#include <direct.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
if(_mkdir("d:\ff") == 0) {
    cout << "success";
} else {
    cout << "fail";
  }
}
```

This program outputs `fail` .why is it so ?

**The compiler that i am using is microsoft visual c++ 2010 express**

Comment: May be you need this: `_mkdir("d:\\ff")`?

Comment: @ Donotalo yes it works. But why the **double slash** ?

Comment: Double backslash `(\\)` is treated as single backslash `(\)` in C/C++. Note, this is not same as slash `(/)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape your back slash.
See this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6aw8xdf2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx for list of escape sequences in C strings.

Comment: the line at web-page says **" If you want a backslash character to appear within a character constant, you must type two backslashes in a row."**, but i dont use the double slash when writing `ofstream writeDetails( "c:/a/b.txt")` this works fine.

Comment: @grassPro: the webpage states about *backslash*, but you've put *slash* in `"c:/a/b.txt"`.

Comment: yes the single slash works when i write `ofstream writeDetails( "c:/a/b.txt")` why it works ? why it does not work here while making directories ?

Comment: @grassPro: `_mkdir("d:/ff")` works on my system. OS: windows xp sp3, compiler: visual c++ 2010 express.